# Diagonal extraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[diagonal Excel CHART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5NqD.png)

I'm attempting to extract diagonal of numbers from CSV file but using .loc doesn't allow to extract more than 3 indexers (IndexingError: Too many indexers):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Norm1.csv')
tf = df.loc[0:0,"BMP2"]
cf = df.loc[1:1,"BTR60"]
df = df.loc[2:2,"BTR70"]
ef = df.loc[3:3,"M1"]
hf = df.loc[4:4,"M109"]
jf = df.loc[5:5,"M110"]
kf = df.loc[6:6,"M113"]
lf = df.loc[7:7,"M2"]
pf = df.loc[8:8,"M35"]
of = df.loc[9:9,"M548"]
uf = df.loc[10:10,"T72"]
yf = df.loc[11:11,"Zil-131"]

print(tf.to_string()) 
print(cf.to_string())
print(df.to_string()) 
print(ef.to_string())
print(hf.to_string()) 
print(jf.to_string())
print(kf.to_string()) 
print(lf.to_string())
print(pf.to_string()) 
print(of.to_string())
print(uf.to_string()) 
print(yf.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.iloc[row, col]` instead.

```py
diag = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   diag.append(df.iloc[i, i])
```

Refrence:[**`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`** <sup>[pandas-docs]</sup>](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html).

```
import numpy as np

out = np.diag(df)

# If you need it back as a dataframe:
out = pd.DataFrame([out], columns=df.columns)
```